# network doesn't start on boot

Tags: networking, server

I installed Ubuntu server on a machine, and there is this thing which is annoying me: everytime I boot the machine, I have to `sudo ifup p1p4` to start the network...
What should I do to make this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set up network connections that are permanent and that you want to be started when you boot in /etc/network/interfaces 
That is the recommended way to set up servers last time I checked.

Comment: guess what: they are on /etc/network/interfaces. Edit: I tried with `auto p1p4` and it is working now

Comment: Yes, you have to include some activation, like auto or other. There are one that initialize the interface when the device get physical connected, not at a computer right now so I can't check. If not activated, you have to activate it manually like you did.

Comment: the `auto` did the trick